# How to look through an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have the code attached below to search through an array for a specific string but this code isn't working. Why? `if(children[x].equals(music))` does work but only if you type in the full file name (stored in the music variable) how can I make it so that if the value of music is 'h' any element in the children array containing the character 'h' will print as an output?

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //text file, should be opening in default text editor   


        //Look through directory
        File dir = new File("/Users/Runa.c/Music/music");
        String[] children = dir.list();

        if (children == null) {
           System.out.println("does not exist or is not a directory");
        } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
              String filename = children[i];
              System.out.println(filename);
           }
        }

        //search
        Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Search for a song: ");
        String music = search.next();


       for (int x=0; x<children.length; x++){
           if(children[x].equals(music)){
               System.out.println(children[x]);
           }
       }



        //Open file
        File file = new File("/Users/Runa.C/Music/music/youtubnow.co - Distrion & Alex Skrindo - Lightning [NCS Release].mp3");

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);

        file = new File("/Users/Runa.C/Music/music/youtubnow.co - Distrion & Alex Skrindo - Lightning [NCS Release].mp3");
        if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);
    search.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does changing the condition to `if(children[x].equals(music))` has any effect?

Comment: If `children[x]` and `music` are expected to be strings, perhaps using `children[x].equals(music)` could help?

Comment: Could you include more code so that we might see what `children[x]` and `music` are?

Comment: its a lot of code, children[x] is an array holding all the .mp3 files from a directory, music is a string holding a user input

Comment: Post the data type of the array and you'll get more answers

Comment: @HrittikChatterjee I hope you mean a String of a .mp3 file? Because no user is going to be able to input an mp3 file...

Comment: @sleepToken yeah thats exactly what I mean. The name of each .mp3 file is shown and the user has to type the full name down how can it be made so that the user can just type in a few characters and ever file with those characters will be the output.

Comment: @HrittikChatterjee if you are comparing Strings you need to use `.equals()` as many others have said. If you can't post any more code after that - no one can really help

Comment: You could use `String`'s `contains` method within your loop. This method checks if the given argument is contained within the string on which the method is called.

Comment: @sleepToken all the code is there now except for the imports because I doubt those are important

Comment: @HrittikChatterjee `if children[x].contains(music)` as @MC Emperor suggests

Comment: Awesome. @MCEmperor if you want to put that in as an answer I can make it the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

if (children[x].equals(music))

You can use:

if (children[x].contains(music))

According to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.